# Android gradle apk splits, setting versionCode

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to split an app into abi specific apks, but the version numbers of all the apks are the same. They need to be different to upload to the play store. Am I missing something?

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this with the latest AS and gradle version I get: Gradle DSL method not found: 'universalapk()'

Answer (score 7):

This is how your Gradle should look like. You have missed assigning an identifier to the different architecture builds.

```
    android 
    {

    def versionMajor = 1
        def versionMinor = 0
        def versionPatch = 0
        def versionBuild = 0

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 22

            versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
            versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
        }

 splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }    

    // map for the version code
        project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            // assign different version code for each output
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks. I tried something like that a while back and it didn't work. but I'll try your code verbatim when I get a chance.

Comment: @TarasVovkovych universalApk true, if in case you need an apk which could run on all the platforms.

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be a bit cleaner. It might not be as 100% automatable though, but I don't like that `* 1000000` and dictionary-lookup trick:

```
ext {
    versionCodeBase = 30 // 1 higher than current highest versionCode in Play store
}

android {
    splits {
        density {
            enable true // just enable them all
        }
        abi {
            enable true
            universalApk false
        }
    }

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.eachWithIndex { output, outputIndex ->
            output.versionCodeOverride = project.ext.versionCodeBase + outputIndex
            println variant.buildType.name + ' - ' + output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI) + ' - ' + output.getFilter(OutputFile.DENSITY) + ': ' + output.versionCodeOverride
        }
    }
}
```

Note I'm looping over the variants using `eachWithIndex`.

This works because density and abi are not going to change on a user's device. More work will be needed in this script if you're going to allow for seperate apk files per `minSdkVersion`.

Lemme just also add the output of the script:

```
debug - mips64 - null: 30
debug - x86_64 - null: 31
debug - x86 - null: 32
debug - armeabi-v7a - null: 33
debug - armeabi - null: 34
debug - mips - null: 35
debug - arm64-v8a - null: 36
debug - mips64 - xxxhdpi: 37
debug - x86_64 - xxxhdpi: 38
debug - x86 - xxxhdpi: 39
debug - armeabi-v7a - xxxhdpi: 40
debug - armeabi - xxxhdpi: 41
debug - mips - xxxhdpi: 42
debug - arm64-v8a - xxxhdpi: 43
debug - mips64 - mdpi: 44
debug - x86_64 - mdpi: 45
debug - x86 - mdpi: 46
debug - armeabi-v7a - mdpi: 47
debug - armeabi - mdpi: 48
debug - mips - mdpi: 49
debug - arm64-v8a - mdpi: 50
debug - mips64 - ldpi: 51
debug - x86_64 - ldpi: 52
debug - x86 - ldpi: 53
debug - armeabi-v7a - ldpi: 54
debug - armeabi - ldpi: 55
debug - mips - ldpi: 56
debug - arm64-v8a - ldpi: 57
debug - mips64 - xxhdpi: 58
debug - x86_64 - xxhdpi: 59
debug - x86 - xxhdpi: 60
debug - armeabi-v7a - xxhdpi: 61
debug - armeabi - xxhdpi: 62
debug - mips - xxhdpi: 63
debug - arm64-v8a - xxhdpi: 64
debug - mips64 - hdpi: 65
debug - x86_64 - hdpi: 66
debug - x86 - hdpi: 67
debug - armeabi-v7a - hdpi: 68
debug - armeabi - hdpi: 69
debug - mips - hdpi: 70
debug - arm64-v8a - hdpi: 71
debug - mips64 - xhdpi: 72
debug - x86_64 - xhdpi: 73
debug - x86 - xhdpi: 74
debug - armeabi-v7a - xhdpi: 75
debug - armeabi - xhdpi: 76
debug - mips - xhdpi: 77
debug - arm64-v8a - xhdpi: 78
release - mips64 - null: 30
release - x86_64 - null: 31
release - x86 - null: 32
release - armeabi-v7a - null: 33
release - armeabi - null: 34
release - mips - null: 35
release - arm64-v8a - null: 36
release - mips64 - xxxhdpi: 37
release - x86_64 - xxxhdpi: 38
release - x86 - xxxhdpi: 39
release - armeabi-v7a - xxxhdpi: 40
release - armeabi - xxxhdpi: 41
release - mips - xxxhdpi: 42
release - arm64-v8a - xxxhdpi: 43
release - mips64 - mdpi: 44
release - x86_64 - mdpi: 45
release - x86 - mdpi: 46
release - armeabi-v7a - mdpi: 47
release - armeabi - mdpi: 48
release - mips - mdpi: 49
release - arm64-v8a - mdpi: 50
release - mips64 - ldpi: 51
release - x86_64 - ldpi: 52
release - x86 - ldpi: 53
release - armeabi-v7a - ldpi: 54
release - armeabi - ldpi: 55
release - mips - ldpi: 56
release - arm64-v8a - ldpi: 57
release - mips64 - xxhdpi: 58
release - x86_64 - xxhdpi: 59
release - x86 - xxhdpi: 60
release - armeabi-v7a - xxhdpi: 61
release - armeabi - xxhdpi: 62
release - mips - xxhdpi: 63
release - arm64-v8a - xxhdpi: 64
release - mips64 - hdpi: 65
release - x86_64 - hdpi: 66
release - x86 - hdpi: 67
release - armeabi-v7a - hdpi: 68
release - armeabi - hdpi: 69
release - mips - hdpi: 70
release - arm64-v8a - hdpi: 71
release - mips64 - xhdpi: 72
release - x86_64 - xhdpi: 73
release - x86 - xhdpi: 74
release - armeabi-v7a - xhdpi: 75
release - armeabi - xhdpi: 76
release - mips - xhdpi: 77
release - arm64-v8a - xhdpi: 78
```

Comment: Note that this is not ideal. The versioncodes need to be ordered properly, xxxhdpi devices will for example take the highest versioncode that will work for them. If xhdpi is a higher versioncode than xxxhdpi, it will run the xhdpi app. Ordering them using the lookup table in the other answer is not such a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I always got errors when using the presented solutions. I have multiple productFlavors and my solution now looks like this:

```
android {
    flavorDimensions 'app', 'store'
    productFlavors {
        appFlavorOne {
            dimension 'app'
            applicationId "com.my.application.id"
            versionCode 123
            versionName '1.2.3'
        }
        appFlavorTwo {
            dimension 'app'
            applicationId "com.my.other.application.id"
            versionCode 100
            versionName '1.0.0'
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
            universalApk true
        }
    }

    // APK Splits based on ABI, map for the version code. Uncomment for appFlavorTwo Builds!
    project.ext.versionCodes = ['null':0, 'armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'x86': 4]
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        // assign different version code for each output
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride = android.productFlavors.appFlavorOne.versionCode + project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0)
            output.versionNameOverride = android.productFlavors.appFlavorOne.versionName + ' (' + (project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) == 0 ? 'universal' : output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)) + ')'
            println output.versionNameOverride + ' (' + output.versionCodeOverride + ')'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Create multiple APKs files for the android application using ABI Filters and APK split

```
splits {
    density {
        enable true
        exclude "ldpi", "tvdpi", "xxxhdpi"
        compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
    }
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        exclude "armeabi", "mips", "mips64", 'x86', 'x86_64'
        universalApk false
    }
}
```